# Get content of webservice

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I've got an URL like [here](http://www.myserver.com/myservice.php?param=foobar). When I type that into Safari's address bar I see an result like "Error" or "OK".

So, how do I properly call that URL from within my code and get that result as a string?

I've tried it with `NSURLConnection`, `NSURLRequest` and `NSURLResponse` but my response object is always `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "response" in those classes refers to the protocol response (HTTP headers, etc.), not the content.

To get the content, you have a few options:

1. Use NSURLConnection in asynchronous mode: [Using NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html)
2. Use NSURLConnection in synchronous mode:

   ```
   // Error checks omitted
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLwithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/myservice.php?param=foobar"];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
   NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                        returningResponse:nil
                                                    error:nil];
   ```
3. Use `[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:]`

   ```
   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLwithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/myservice.php?param=foobar"];
   NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL];
   ```

Of course, you should use options 2 and 3 **only if** your content will be really small in size, to maintain responsiveness.

Comment: Thank you! Number two did it for me. :)