# how to send request to url and get data into string

Tags: iphone, ipad

I do have a url which contains data of stream.

I need to load the data into NSString.

@all

help me out.

Comment: well Matt Ball not.  thats my task for this hour.

Comment: Well, when you do, come back and tell us what you've tried and what isn't working for you.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to solve this problem and each depends on your circumstance. The first would be to use the `+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error` method of NSString. So if you wanted to get the contents of some URL you could use the following code

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://www.someUrl.com/some/path"];
NSString* urlContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8Encoding error:nil];
```

The issue with this approach is that it will block whatever thread you call that on. So you can either call it in a thread or use one of the other approaches.

The second approach is to use NSURLConnection. This uses delegates to handle the process in an event driven fashion. There is a good summary of that approach [here](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/).

The third approach is to use some kind of wrapper class that handles http requests at a higher level. Personally I like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/). It can handle requests synchronous, asynchronous using delegates, and asynchronous using blocks. The following examples are from the [ASIHTTPRequest website](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). This example shows how to do an asynchronous HTTP request.

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setDelegate:self];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   // Use when fetching text data
   NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

   // Use when fetching binary data
   NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
   NSError *error = [request error];
}
```

This example shows you how to do an asynchronous request using blocks as the callbacks intsead of delegate methods. Note that this can only be used in iOS 4.0 and greater since it uses blocks. But ASIHTTPRequest in general can be used on iOS 3.0 and greater without blocks.

```
- (IBAction)grabURLInBackground:(id)sender
{
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com"];
   __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [request setCompletionBlock:^{
      // Use when fetching text data
      NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

      // Use when fetching binary data
      NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
   }];
   [request setFailedBlock:^{
      NSError *error = [request error];
   }];
   [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: Such a long response for a closed question with no upvotes :(, btw you only have to declare a variable as `__block` if you plan on changing the value, it is guaranteed to exist readonly for the duration of block without `__block`.

Comment: @Joe: In this case it's for avoiding a retain cylce.

Comment: @Nikolai: any chance you can explain?

Comment: @Joe: To be honest I just guessed the reason. But the idea is: An `ASIHTTPRequest` probably retains its completion block. If the `request` variable would not be declared `__block`, the block would retain the `request` object (Objects from surrounding scope are retained by blocks). To prevent the resulting retain cycle it's a common pattern to declare the variable with the `__block` storage modifier.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myURL];
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

You have to know the encoding to do this right.

Answer (score 0):

Kiran,

Try the solution provided here :

[Get content of webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3249897/get-content-of-webservice)

Answer (score -2):

Well, your going to have to work out to how to encode each byte into it's equivalent string compatible representing. In .Net, we use Base64 encoding. I'm sure in the iWorld there is something equivalent.